# How to cancel http requests made by Apollo (angular) client?

Tags: apollo-client

I noticed that when I unsubscribe from query, http request is still executing and not being canceled. Also tried to use AbortController but without any luck. How does one cancel http requests made by Apollo client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question, but since I just wanted to do the same and managed to do it with the latest Apollo Client (3.4.13) and Apollo-Angular (2.6.0), you need to make sure that you're using `watchQuery()` instead of `query()`, and then call `unsubscribe()` on the returned Apollo subscription from the previous request. The latter implies of course that you should store somewhere the subscription object that you want to abort.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I spent two days on this bananas problem and I want to share for posterity.

We're using Angular and GraphQL (apollo-angular and codegen to make GraphQL services) and we opted for an event-driven architecture using NgRx to send events and then perform http calls. When sending multiple identical events (but with different property values) we noticed we got stale data in some cases, especially edge cases like when 20+ of these identical events were sent. Obviously not common, but not ideal, and a hint of perhaps bad scale since we were going to need many more events in future.

The way we resolved this issue was by using .watch() instead of .fetch() on the GraphQL generated services. Initially, since .fetch() returned the same Observable as .watch().valueChanges, we thought it was easier and simpler to just use .fetch(), but their behavior seems much different. We were never able to cancel http requests performed by .fetch(). But after changing to .watch().valueChanges, the Observable acted exactly as http request Observables would, complete with -- thankfully -- cancelation.

So in NgRx, we swapped our generic mergeMap operator for the switchMap operator. This will ensure previous effects listening on dispatched events will be canceled. We needed no extra overhead, no .next-ing to Subjects, no extra Subscriptions. Just change .fetch() into .watch().valueChanges and then switchMap to your heart's content. The takeUntil operator will now also cancel these requests, which is our performed method of unsubscribing from Observables.

Sidenote: I'm amazed that this information was this hard to come by, and honestly this question and [one GitHub issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4150) was all I could find to intimate this discrepancy. Even now I don't quite understand why anyone would want .fetch() if all it does is perform an http call that will always resolve and then return an Observable that does not behave the way you expect Observables to behave.